# oracle apex chart - line graph sql?

Tags: sql, charts, oracle-apex, linegraph

```
select count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 1 then 1 end) as Jan,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 2 then 1 end) as feb,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 3 then 1 end) as mar,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 4 then 1 end) as april,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 5 then 1 end) as may,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 6 then 1 end) as jun,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 7 then 1 end) as jul,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 8 then 1 end) as aug,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 9 then 1 end) as sep,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 10 then 1 end) as oct,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 11 then 1 end) as nov,
   count(case when extract(month from C_DATE) = 12 then 1 end) as december
from Table1
```

Currently That is the query i have which produces the result

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr .....
1   3    1   2
```

now i want to display this information in a line graph so it looks like this joined up

```
3       x
2
1  x           x
  jan   feb   mar
```

Being abit of a noob with charts i cant get it to work when i try to use my current query. any help much appreciated

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? What is the maximum count to be expected?

Comment: I am using oracle apex 4.1 maximum count expected is 100

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go with ASCII graphics, and in lieu of something more elaborate, you could build on

```
WITH
Line AS (
  SELECT
    ' ' || Jan || '  ' || Feb || '  ' || Mar || '  ' || Apr || '  ' || May || '  ' || Jun || '  ' || Jul || '  ' || Aug || '  ' || Sep || '  ' || Oct || '  ' || Nov || '  ' || Dec || ' ' l
  FROM Result
),
Graph (cnt, g)AS (
  SELECT 5, '#' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(l, ' 5 ', '  x  '), '\d+', '   ') || '#' FROM Line UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '#' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(l, ' 4 ', '  x  '), '\d+', '   ') || '#' FROM Line UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '#' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(l, ' 3 ', '  x  '), '\d+', '   ') || '#' FROM Line UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '#' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(l, ' 2 ', '  x  '), '\d+', '   ') || '#' FROM Line UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '#' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(l, ' 1 ', '  x  '), '\d+', '   ') || '#' FROM Line UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, '#' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(l, ' 0 ', '  x  '), '\d+', '   ') || '#' FROM Line UNION ALL
  SELECT -1, '# Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec #' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  *
FROM Graph
ORDER BY cnt DESC
;
```

with "Result" being your query against Table1.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39614) (Switch to plain text output to see the columns properly aligned.)
Did you give [Building Charts, Gantts and Maps with Oracle Application Express 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r40/apexcharts/apexcharts_ll.htm) a try?
Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.